# Is there an analogue of MathSciNet for philosophy?

Tags: reference-request

MathSciNet is a mathematical database for papers and books on the various branches of math. Is there something analogous for philosophy? That is, is there a philosophical database for papers and books on the various branches of philosophy?

Comment: The closest thing is [PhilPapers](https://philpapers.org/), but it is not nearly as organized.